# Looking for better ways to style JSON object data retrieved using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, json, smarty, styling

I'm using AJAX in my website to get a JSON string generated by a PHP script. The JSON object looks something like:

```
{
  "people" : [
    { "name" : "Bob", "id" : "1", "sex" : "m" }, 
    { "name" : "Amy", "id" : "2", "sex" : "f" }
  ]
}
```

Once I retrieve it using AJAX, I'm styling it manually using Javascript

```
for(i = 0; i < obj.people.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById('people-container').innerHtml += '<span class=\'' + obj.people[i].sex + ' person\'>' + obj.people[i].name + '</span>
}
```

but I can't help but have a feeling of guilt for having HTML and classes embedded in my Javascript, since I'm using the *Smarty template engine* for all my other, non-AJAX content.

I figured I can't use Smarty for my AJAX responses since the template engine runs on page load, and AJAX calls are done after the page loads... is there a better way I could be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful if you put some sample code. However if I'm understanding you correctly I would use my AJAX call to return something like this:

```
{
  "html": "<span>...${sex}.. ${name}</span>",
  "people" : [
    { "name" : "Bob", "id" : "1", "sex" : "m" }, 
    { "name" : "Amy", "id" : "2", "sex" : "f" }
  ]
}
```

You can then use your JS to append the markup to the page for whatever templating engine you want. And obviously you can loop through the returned data as well which would take advantage of the template.

```
// Don't append more than once if multiple ajax calls
if ( !document.getElementById( 'people-template' ).length ) {

  // Append template to page
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/html';
  script.id = "people-template";
  document.body.appendChild( script );

}

for(i = 0; i < obj.people.length; i++) {

  // Using jQuery + jQuery templating here as an example
  // Never used smarty but I hope this shows you the idea well enough
  $('#people-container').innerHtml += $('#people-template').tmpl( obj );

}
```

Comment: I updated my post to be more precise and include code. Hopefully my question is clearer!

I don't want to add HTML in my JSON object since it's generated by a PHP script and I don't want to mix in view markup in my PHP logic.